# Variables goes Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some variable in my DataEntityLayer which are common for all the users for example

```
public class DataEntityLayer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["UserName"] == null)
                {
                    GotoLoginPage();
                    return null;
                }
                else
                    return Session["UserName"].ToString();
            }

            set { Session["UserName"] = value; }
        }
}
```

I am using this variable to display Username when a user logs in, this is working fine but goes null frequently. How can I avoid that or let me know a way to declare a variable in my Layer to show Username of a user when he logs in.

Answer (score 5):

Session is temporary memory that expires after a defined amount of time, I believe the default is 20 minutes of inactivity.

It could also be because you're using multiple servers with load balancing. Unless the session is persisted in a database then as you move from one server to another, the session is lost.

I would recommend avoiding this approach for the above reasons. There are better and more secure ways to handle authentication.

P.S An object called DataEntityLayer should not derive from System.Web.UI.Page!!

Comment: I need to instantiate my Dataentitylayer in each class where I have to use the variable of it??

Comment: It's just the naming contention. By deriving from System.Web.UI.Page it is a web page, so it couldn't be further from being a something related to data access. In relation to authentication, I would recommend using something like .Net Identity. You don't know much about security (not do I), so let the experts look after that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with @johnMc in regards to the security, best use a library or package that gives a total solution. For completeness, the reason for the session being lost could be also running the service on a multi-threaded application. If using IIS, you can turn on a service called "ASP.Net state service" and then enable it in your web config. This does out-of-process session handling for ASP.net. There is also a way to connect to this service using non-IIS, but you'll have to build a communicator class to handle this. There is a small performance hit for this process, but I've never had any issues on high loads.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" />
</system.web>
```

(I would've commented, but I can't add a comment yet?) :)